# Is there a way to monitor which disks are spun down in a Mac Pro?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mac-pro

I have an 2009 Mac Pro full of disks, most of them seldom used (boots on a SSD). Is there a way to see which disks are spun down at a given time (currently running 10.6.8)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid this isn't made possible by the S.M.A.R.T (Self-Monitoring, Analysis and Reporting Technology) system that is used to provide details of Hard Drive operation, I was hoping to find a [SMART attribute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T) that details the current 'park' status, but it seems that there simply isn't one, and as this is a low level activity that is fully handled by the drive itself without any OS input I cannot see a way of ever retrieving the status as the value isn't available in the first place.